# Jupyterlab extension jupyterlab_templates not finding template files

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I'm trying to work with the `jupyterlab_templates` extension. For some reason, it's not finding the corresponding template files, even though I've set the correct path?
When running `jupyter lab`, it finds the extension and confirms the search path I set, but isn't finding any files:

```
[I 2022-01-11 18:10:09.108 ServerApp] jupyterlab_templates | extension was successfully loaded.
Installing jupyterlab_templates handler on path /templates
Search paths:
    /Users/emilaz/.jupyter/templates
Available templates:

[I 2022-01-11 18:10:09.108 ServerApp] jupyterlab_templates.extension | extension was successfully loaded.
```

Here is what the content of `/Users/my_username/.jupyter/templates` looks like:

```
$ ls /Users/emilaz/.jupyter/templates
new_template.ipynb  some_template.ipynb
```

Here is my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file:

```
c.JupyterLabTemplates.template_dirs = ['/Users/emilaz/.jupyter/templates']
c.JupyterLabTemplates.include_default = False
c.JupyterLabTemplates.include_core_paths = False
```

I've tried

1. un- and reinstalling both `jupyterlab` and `jupyterlab_templates`
2. changing the permission on the template files to 660
3. running `jupyter trust` on the two files.
4. moving the files elsewhere (in a non-hidden folder)

I then tried to include the default templates (set `c.JupyterLabTemplates.include_default=True`, `c.JupyterLabTemplates.include_core_paths=True`). This makes the sample template available for selection. I then tried to move my own `.ipynb` files into the same folder as the sample template `ipynb`, but they still don't show.

The package versions are

`jupyterlab==3.2.6`

`jupyterlab-templates==0.3.1`

Comment: Strange error, could you try this in your config file instead? `c.JupyterLabTemplates.template_dirs = ['/Users/emilaz/.jupyter']`. This is because in the docs it says 'You must put the templates in subdirectories'.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution: add os link to your template_dir near the folder where it sees Sample.ipynb